# Backup with RHEL Cockpit

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, cockpit

Using cockpit [cockpit-project.org](https://cockpit-project.org/), I was wondering what you would need to backup. Is it just backup the VM images and then dump em back in the same directory as I would any other virtualization control panel or is there something else I should be looking for?

Googling turns up a bunch of stuff about cockpit CMS and something to do with SAP so Im not sure where to go thanks!

Comment: I guess you could do that, but there's nothing specific to Cockpit about copying VM images. A cron job can do that.

Comment: thats what I was wondering I have set something similar up on older openvz hosts what I wasn't sure if there was some sort of machine registration configs or something else Id have to worry about

Comment: The virtual machine configuration files are in `/etc/libvirt`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes I was wondering if there was anything else Id have to worry about adding in cockpit in addition to those